# Is it better to synchronize with semaphores or with monitors?

Tags: java, synchronization, monitor

Is it better to synchronize with semaphores or with monitors?

Comment: what's your specific problem that requires synchronization?

Comment: generally either is better than the other, at the same time also worse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Better" depends on context. They are "equally powerful" according to James McParlane. I highly recommend viewing [his blog for a discussion on the differences](http://blog.metawrap.com/2004/11/09/semaphore-vs-monitor/).

Here is a quick guide I found:

**Semaphores**

- Can be used anywhere in a program, but should not be used in a monitor
- `Wait()` does not always block the caller (i.e., when the semaphore counter is greater than zero).
- `Signal()` either releases a blocked thread, if there is one, or increases the semaphore counter.
- If `Signal()` releases a blocked thread, the caller and the released thread both continue.

**Condition Variables**

- Can only be used in monitors
- `Wait()` always blocks the caller.
- `Signal()` either releases a blocked thread, if there is one, or the signal is lost as if it never happens.
- If `Signal()` releases a blocked thread, the caller yields the monitor (Hoare type) or continues (Mesa Type). Only one of the caller or the released thread can continue, but not both.

This information from: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/MONITOR/sema-vs-monitor.html

Some useful resources:

- [What is a Semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore)
- [Looking for Good Analogy Examples for Monitor Versus Semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836301/looking-for-good-analogy-examples-for-monitor-verses-semaphore)
- [What are the differences between various threading synchronization options in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301160/what-are-the-differences-between-various-threading-synchronization-options-in-c)

Comment: This is interesting in general but is not directly applicable to Java, and hence slightly confusing. Hoare and Mesa monitors wha?

Comment: Yes, the question was asked for Java, but the answer is not related to Java.

Answer (score 10):

If you are after headache minimization, **prefer the monitors** (`synchronized` blocks/methods) over semaphores wherever you feel a real choice of a locking primitive.
Ignore academical talk about flexibility of semaphores.  You are after reliability, not configurability, aren't you?

It is often claimed that monitors and semaphores are equivalent (can simulate each other), but this equivalence is far more abstract and less helpful than is [sometimes expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253150/implementation-of-monitors-with-semaphores/10253295#10253295).
Anyone who can *correctly* simulate one with the other does not need any answer to this question anymore.

Obviously, semaphores are your only practical choice in situations where the number of threads to be allowed to simultaneously enter a block is larger than one.  So the real competitor of monitors are **binary semaphores**, namely those that are initialized with a count of 1, and additionally only those of them where you expect the same thread that did the locking to eventually unlock the semaphore.  So let's look closer at exactly those situations.

The fundamental difference between monitors and binary semaphores is **thread ownership**.  It has a big consequence, and that is the capability of **reentrancy**.  Reentrancy means that a thread that already owns a lock can acquire it again as opposed to deadlocking.  This is a big deal if your class has shared state that you simply want to protect in all methods but cannot afford permanent assumptions about how these methods call each other; or with any belt and braces traits that evolve in your thread safety scheme in general.

**Semaphores are never reentrant and Java monitors are always reentrant.**  If you need to lock the same object from many code locations, [semaphores are prone to deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253150/implementation-of-monitors-with-semaphores/10253295#10253295) even in single threaded scenarios - and this limitation of semaphores brings any benefits only in relatively rare scenarios where monitors are not really an option anyway.

Thread ownership also drammatically reduces the risk of forgetting to lock, forgetting to unlock, or one thread's activities masking activities of another thread.  There is also a significant ergonomic difference in the associated Java syntax.

Notice also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference); although it uses a different terminology, the better answers there understand "mutex" to mean a Java "monitor".

Comment: "Obviously, semaphores are your only practical choice in situations where the number of threads to be allowed to simultaneously enter a block is larger than one."   - Can't we maintain a counter and do a "while(not count<MAX) cv.wait()". By doing this we can control how many threads enter the critical section

Comment: @matrixisreal - It is possible to simulate a semaphore using a combination of a mutex and a condition variable.  You aren't mentioning the mutex so your suggestion/question is too vague.  Unprotected CVs generally tend to lose signals.

Comment: @matrixisreal - For simulation of one primitive using others in general, see the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @matrixisreal - If you would want to avoid both semaphores and CVs and build a semaphore using mutexes alone, you [will have to busy wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534782/implementing-semaphore-by-using-mutex-operations-and-primitives).  That could be OK if there's almost no contention... if the semaphore is barely even needed in the application.

Comment: maybe I misused some names. before calling cv.wait(), I presumed acquiring a lock on mutex. I was just thinking in terms of java monitors more so than mutex/cv pair in C++. So yes, I agree that semaphores and monitors are equivalent, but saying "Obviously, semaphores are your only practical choice in situations where the number of threads to be allowed to simultaneously enter a block is larger than one." contradicts the equivalence right? Coz we can use monitors too for the same purpose.

Comment: @matrixisreal - No, this answer is purposefully dodging the question of equivalence, and CVs are off topic entirely.  Please note that "equivalent" is a super-loose term if a random third primitive is needed to make a simulation fly.  Mutexes also have additional golden virtues not even touched on here, such as priority inheritance.  This answer suggests: use mutexes over semaphores everywhere where you feel that either way would be comparably easy - if your goal is headache minimization.  (Someone might not even know what priority inversion or self-deadlock is in order to benefit.)

Comment: @matrixisreal - Feel free to edit the answer if you feel that my point can be expressed somehow more clearly.   But I'm skeptical that CVs could become the clarifying ingredient, given how the OP is formulated.

Answer (score 4):

To confirm, by *monitors* we mean the good old `synchronized` keyword.

First question, do you need your lock to have a counter?

1. A Semaphore can have a **counter greater than one**. If you need to protect N resources, the Semaphore is best. Easy decision.
2. If you're protecting a single resource, this is the interesting case where a Semaphore(1) and monitor are equally applicable.

The [J2SE 5.0 concurrency article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/) gives great advice here. Monitors are limited because :

- **No way to back off** from an attempt to acquire a lock that is already held, or to give up after waiting for a specified period of time, or to cancel a lock attempt after an interrupt.
- **No way to alter the semantics** of a lock, for example, with respect to reentrancy, read versus write protection, or fairness.
- Synchronization is done within methods and blocks, thus limiting use to strict block-structured locking. In other words, **you cannot acquire a lock in one method and release it in another**.

So if any of these items is important to you - backing off after a timeout is a great example - then go with a Semaphore. If not, a monitor is fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to decide which JDK are you using.
The first Java releases where only provided of Threads. Since the Java Tiger (5.0), new classes have been introduced to handle concurrency. 
In particular, a complete package has been provided, the **java.util.concurrent**.

In my experience, I found that monitors are better, since they let the code more clean. Moreover, using them let the code more *easy-to-understand*. They are generally implemented through a class that implements the **Lock** interface: the most famous implementations provided by the JDK are the **ReentrantLock** class, which defines a general lock, and the **ReentrantReadWriteLock** class, that provides a specific *write* and/or *read* lock.

Threfore, a lock is used to enable/disable the access to a shared object (e.g. a list of objects).

A **Semaphore** object is a synchronized used to coordinate and control the threads (there are many synchronizers provided in the latest JDKs, like *Semaphore*, *CyclicBarrier*, *CountdownLatch*, and *Exchanger* classes). 
For instance, with a Semaphore you can release a fixed number of tokens to your pool of Threads and so decide the amount of operations that can be executed simultaneously. Personally, I don't like this approach, since the use of a pool of thread with Futures and Locks lead to the same result in a cleaner and safer way.

More info can be found in this book: "[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)" and in this IBM's tutorial: "[Concurrency in JDK 5.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-concur/)". Some more nice examples can be found [here](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com).