# Implementation of monitors with semaphores

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, semaphore, locks

I've been asked the following question and I'm not sure what the correct answer is to it:

```
If monitors are implemented by replacing condition variables with semaphores 
(counters set to 0) with down() and up() as wait and signal, respectively,
would the monitors work correctly?
```

I'd be tempted to say it is a correct implementation because semaphores and condition variables can replace each other, correct? Is there a better explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about a semaphore initialized to 1, which is also called a **binary semaphore**.

The answer depends on a particular implementation (or definition) of these primitives, however a typical difference is that monitors have thread ownership and semaphores do not.  This impacts a variety of scenarios.

- For a semaphore, it is completely normal that one thread does all the ups and another one does all the downs.  This should not be allowed by monitors.
- Suppose you have a class with private state and multiple public methods, all of which lock a common monitor upon entry and unlock upon exit in order to protect that state.  Suppose also that public method `A` internally calls public method `B`.  Then a recursive monitor will correctly allow calling method `A` (which involves a sequence lock-lock-unlock-unlock) whereas the same with a semaphore-implemented monitor would result in a deadlock upon the second attempt to lock, using the same thread.
- Suppose that a thread acquires a named system wide monitor and crashes.  Because of thread ownership, it is possible to automatically unlock the monitor and allow any waiting threads to acquire it.  With a binary semaphore this is not possible, and such a situation will typically never resolve satisfactorily until a reboot.  [**Edit**: Note that even in case of a mutex, the described recovery mechanism may not be desirable or enabled by default, as the state of the protected resources or data structures is basically undefined after a crash midway.  The decision whether to re-acquire or to recover differently is typically left to application code.]

So, a binary semaphore is similar to a monitor, but do not expect it to behave identically.