# Do I need to use atomic<> if already guard by mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Given the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534782/implementing-semaphore-by-using-mutex-operations-and-primitives), to implement `Semaphore` using only `atomic<>` and `mutex`.

I'm just curious that since `count` is already guarded by `updateMutex`, is `atomic<>` necessary?

```
struct Semaphore {
    int size;
    atomic<int> count;
    mutex updateMutex;

    Semaphore(int n) : size(n) { count.store(0); }

    void aquire() {
        while (1) {
            while (count >= size) {}
            updateMutex.lock();
            if (count >= size) {
                updateMutex.unlock();
                continue;
            }
            ++count;
            updateMutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
    }

    void release() {
        updateMutex.lock();
        if (count > 0) {
            --count;
        } // else log err
        updateMutex.unlock();
    }
};
```

Without `atomic`, I think the constructor would get synchronization problem. Assignment to count might not be visible if other threads are using it right after the construction.

If so, what about `size`? Does it also need to be protected by `atomic<>`?

Or the `atomic<>` is totally useless because both `size` and `count` will be visible no matter when other threads use them.

Thanks!

Comment: How can a *constructor* have a synchronisation problem?!

Comment: @KerrekSB Because the writes to `size` and `count` might not be immediately visible to threads on other core if no memory barrier is set, can't they?

Comment: How can the other threads even *know* of an object that doesn't exist?

Comment: @KerrekSB You are right. If that do happen, then whatever synchronization is meaningless.

Comment: `size` and `count` are non-static members, so they cannot be accessed on other threads before constructor finishes: there is no object

Comment: @KerrekSB: memory reordering

Comment: @immibis: I maintain that you'd have to struggle extremely hard to contrive a situation where a multi-threaded program that would not already have undefined behaviour otherwise would be broken because of a data race in a constructor concerning member variables.

Comment: @KerrekSB: double checked locking?

Comment: @KerrekSB The C++ memory model assumes that without explicit barriers, writes in one thread eventually become available to another, with the time required being undefined.   The worst case is essentially *never*.  Remember that inter-CPU synchronisation is expensive and possibly slow. Especially with NUMA architectures.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's pretty easy for the constructor to have a problem: what happens if there is a write-back cache? Well, the second thread obtains the address of the newly-constructed object and reads its `count` field -- but the cache containing the field's value has not yet flushed its contents to memory, and hence the thread will read an old value. Caching is the key here -- if you don't see why something is wrong, consider what happens if everyone performed optimistic caching.

Comment: @Mehrdad I can think of 2 cases when the problem of ctor happen: 1. the semaphore is passed to a newly created thread; 2. a existing thread try to get resource, but resource owner create semaphore on the fly. In the first case, can it happen? In the second, if the resource create the semaphore using lazy initialization, it's a bad implementation.

Comment: @XinHuang: Yes -- when the semaphore is "passed", its *address* is passed. But you haven't performed any synchronization, so there is *nothing* that guarantees any particular value to be visible to the other thread in the memory *at* that address -- the memory can be entirely uninitialized! The changes that the first thread has made can be entirely local (in cache), and they might not have propagated to memory. Hence it's quite dangerous to assume the second thread will see anything in particular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple questions asked. All require that the underlying concept is understood: you have a *data race* if one object is written by at least one thread which is accessed (read or written) by another thread and the write and the access are not synchronized. The formal definition of data races is in 1.10 [intro.multithread] paragraph 21:

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. [...]

A program which contains a data race has undefined behavior, i.e., the program needs to make sure that it is data race free. Now on to answering the different questions:

1. Is it necessary to use synchronization in the constructor?

   It depends on whether the object may be access concurrently by different threads while it is still under construction. The only case I can imagine concurrent access to an object under construction is during static initialization where multiple thread are already kicked off accessing the shared object. Due to the weak constraints on the order of construction for global objects I can't imagine that global objects would be used anyway and construction of function local `static` objects is synchronized by the implementation. Otherwise, I would expect that a reference to the object would shared across threads using a suitably synchronized mechanism. That is, I would design the system such that the constructor doesn't require synchronization.
2. There is a lock already. Does that mean that `count` doesn't have to be an atomic.

   Since `count` is accessed in the `acquire()` function before lock is obtained, it would be an unsynchronized access to an object which is written by another thread, i.e., you'd have a data race and, hence, undefined behavior. The `count` has to be atomic.
3. Is it necessary for `size` to be synchronized, too.

   The `size` member is only modified in the constructor of `Semaphore` and it might be reasonable to enforce that by actually making it a `const` member. Assuming the object isn't concurrently accessed during construction (see 1. above) there is no potential for a data race when accessing `size`.

Note that you shouldn't really make unguarded use of the `lock()` and `unlock()` members of the mutex. Instead, you should use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` or `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, potentially with an auxiliary block. These two classes guarantee that an acquired lock will always be released. I'd also question if a busy wait for a semaphore acquiring a lock anyway is the right way to go.

Comment: Sometimes people write code like `while (dontstop) { run(); }`, where `dontstop` is a non-atomic variable controlled in another thread. Like in this case, it's read-only. I think the "undefined behavior" refers to the value read from `count` is undetermined, am I right?

Comment: @XinHuang: If `dontstop` is a non-synchronized object, e.g., a `bool`, `char`, `int`, ..., which is written by another thread, there is a data race and the program has undefined behavior. The rule as simple: if one thread writes and another thread reads synchronization is needed. Without synchronization you have undefined behavior. No exceptions. Have a look at [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) on "benign" data races.

Answer (score 7):

I think the real reason for `count` to be an `atomic<int>` is that is is *read* in `aquire()` **outside** of the `mutex`-protected area in this line:

```
while (count >= size) {}
```

Without `atomic`, the compile is allowed to assume that reading it once is enough and it will not poll it for changed values from other threads.

Comment: The *why* of your answer is practically correct, but the *how* of it describes volatility (`volatile`) rather than atomicity (`atomic<T>`).

Comment: @pilcrow The "how" I referred to only shows one aspect of `atomic` that is used in this case. `volatile` shares this aspect but it is different as it would allow re-ordering of other memory accesses and it doesn't allow the compiler to understand what you are really trying to achieve. Maybe that's not a problem in this particular case, but in general I'd prefer `atomic` for multi-threaded code and `volatile` for accessing hardware registers.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. But sometimes people write code like `while (dontstop) { run(); }`, where `dontstop` is a non-atomic variable controlled in another thread. It's read-only, and there's guard with lock following. Would be atomic necessary?

Comment: @XinHuang If the compiler can see that `run()` does not touch `dontstop` and `dontstop` is non-atomic, the compiler is allowed to turn the code into `if(dontstop) while(true) run();`. No memory barrier will help you then. Technically, it's undefined behaviour so anything can happen. So yes, atomic is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is a theoretical risk that:

`count = 0;`

in the constructor would not be observed by a different threading running on another CPU in time for a subsequent call to either `acquire()` or `release()`.    The possibility of this happening is likely to be vanishingly small as the in order to use the semaphore object, the constructor must complete and somehow another thread needs to get hold of the object.

This is to say that the other CPU's view of the memory occupied by `count` would not be synchronised between CPUs, and another could read an old (e.g. uninitialised) value.

Using an `std::atomic<int>` here by default generates memory barriers around the loads (in this case via overloaded operators) and stores.  By default, this is ultra-conservative. .

You could also lock and unlock the mutex in the constructor for the same effect - but this is even more expensive.

It must be said that this is a pretty nasty way of implementing a counting semaphore - but it was afterall an interview question, and as such has a lot of facets.

Comment: So, thread A could construct an object, pass the resulting address to thread B, and thread B receives this address, but the memory operations that happened in the constructor have not been synchronized there? Doesn’t that violate the sequential consistency of the memory model? Or is this an effect that could only transpire for placement new?

Comment: There are no guarantees of the order in which memory writes complete with respect to memory.  It's entirely possible that a write of a pointer to a `semaphore` object could complete and be visible to thread B before data stored in the object.   I'd hazard a guess that the C++ standard is not mandating a store barrier in every constructor?

Comment: The C++11 memory model has the basic sequential consistency guarantee for programs without race conditions, I thought? I believe that is what Scott Meyers teaches, anyway. So, if I store the address of the object after its constructor has succeeded, anyone who sees that stored address will also see initialized members, no?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: No, there is no reason to believe the address becomes visible to the second thread *after* the rest of the data is visible. Why? Because you haven't performed any synchronization. It is entirely possible that the second thread sees the address before the contents at that location are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. I re-watched Herb Sutter’s atomic<> Weapons talk and think I’ve learned a little bit more today.

Comment: Although … storing into `count` is a release operation. Returning from the constructor, storing the pointer in some global, reading it from another thread and entering some method could happen before the write. And the read itself doesn’t wait for the write either, so I think we need an `atomic` for the semaphore object itself, and having a data member be atomic does not help in ensuring a properly constructed object. Even if that store is properly the last operation. Is that obviously wrong, would it be worth putting into a question of my own, or should we continue this in the chat?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig If you're storing a pointer to a object in a global that is shared between threads, absolutely. You'd need to take care that there is a memory barrier there as well.  This is another really good reason to not use global variables in a multi-threaded environment...  If on the other hand you spawned a new thread passing the pointer as a parameter, no problem - the operating system takes care of it for you.

Comment: @marko But in that case, I wouldn’t need the atomic member either to ensure that the object was completely constructed, by the as-if rule. (I obviously need basically the same kind of memory barrier for any other communication with existing threads, for the same reason as for a global. It seemed just easiest to describe.)